# Early 90s anime or cartoon series in which the main character carries a magic gem or stone that grants him power when placed on his belt buckle

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I remember the intro showing a meteor storm/shower while two friends were surveying a planet/moon and he is forced to leave his friend behind that ends up as the villain, turned into a half-man, half-machine.

The last thing I remember is that when he face the villain, he gives him the stone and turns him back to human. I believe the main character carries it on his belt buckle.

It was a TV series or episodes. I watched it in Puerto Rico on channel 2 or 4. The name could be different from the original, because I can’t find anything at all.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What country did you see this in?  Any idea what channel it would have been on?

Comment: Puerto Rico channel 2 or 4. The name could be different from the original because I can’t find anything at all. Thanks

Comment: Was this a series or a movie?

Comment: It was a TV series or episodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ***[Space Strikers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0488469/)*** (1995).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Strikers):

> *Space Strikers* (French: *20,000 Lieues dans l'espace*, lit *20,000 Leagues in Space*) is a 1995 animated television series based on the 1870 Jules Verne novel *Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea*. Episodes center around the crew of the spaceship Nautilus, led by Captain Nemo, in an attempt to liberate Earth and other planets from the control of Master Phantom.

From the [90s Cartoons Wiki](https://90scartoons.fandom.com/wiki/Space_Strikers):

> ***Space Strikers* follows the outer space exploits of a descendant of Verne's Captain Nemo. Captain Nemo captains a heavily-armed super spacecraft, the Nautilus,** which more closely resembles a submarine than a rocket ship. His crew members include: Ned Land, a fellow human, Dakkar, a man from another planet who has been transformed to resemble a wolf, a robot named Aronnax, and a blonde female named Dana.
>
> **Nemo and his crew battle Master Phantom, who believes he is destined to rule the galaxy. Before adopting the identity of Master Phantom, he was once human, and a close friend of Nemo's when the two were youths at the space academy. However, Phantom believes Nemo deliberately abandoned him on an asteroid during a meteor shower. Wounded, his life was saved by the evil Metallic, who turned him into a Darth Vader-type figure, part-man, part-machine.**
>
> Each episode depicts an encounter between the two adversaries, on distant planets and abandoned space stations. While Master Phantom has unlimited resources and fleets of spacecraft to hurl at the Nautilus, **Nemo must rely on clever tactics to outwit his adversary. He also has the power of "the stone of Solara," a magical talisman which for brief periods can make Nemo almost invincible.**

In the first episode, we're shown flashbacks revealing that the cyborg antagonist, Master Phantom, was once a normal human and a friend of the protagonist, Captain Nemo. When they were younger, the pair were sent on a mission to collect rock samples from an asteroid, and Nemo was forced to leave his friend behind on the asteroid as a consequence of them being hit by a meteorite storm. The friend was subsequently rebuilt into a cyborg by an alien robot called Metallic.

In the third episode, an alien member of Nemo's crew called Victory gives him the Stone of Solara, a magical talisman that is the most prized possession of Victory's people. The stone grants Nemo strength and power, and he wears it on his belt in later episodes.

You can view the show's intro below, which briefly recaps the backstory between Nemo and Master Phantom, and includes a shot of the aforementioned meteorite storm.

Comment: OMG YES THANK YOU SO MUCH I been looking for this for so many years.

Comment: Odd that they went with such a generic title for the US. The literal translation of the French title is much better in my opinion.